# Parallel building with gnumake and prerequisites

Tags: makefile, parallel-processing, gnu-make

My first question (yay!) is about gnumake and parallel builds.  Here's a quick example file:

```
.PHONY: tool_1 tool_2 tool_3 tool_4 all tools

all: | tools

tools: | tool_2 tool_3 tool_4

tool_1:
    # commands for tool 1

tool_2: | tool_1
    # commands for tool 2

tool_3: | tool_1
    # commands for tool 3

tool_4: | tool_1
    # commands for tool 4
```

If I do `make -j` on this guy, is what I have here correct to ensure that the commands for `tool_1` are executed exactly once, and before `make` tries to build any of `tool_[234]`?

What I'm looking for is to have `make -j` cause `tool_1` to be built first, then `tool_[234]` to be built in parallel, but without executing the commands for `tool_1` three times.  I hope that makes sense.  Thanks for any suggestions or ideas!

Comment: It does *seem* to be working like I want it to, but this parallel build stuff has a way of changing behaviour based on system load or from machine to machine, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`make -j` behaves exactly as you expect in your question.  It does not make dependencies multiple times.

What does that pipe (`|`) character do in your dependency list?

Comment: order-only prerequisites: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types

Comment: That's great, thanks @Alex.  I couldn't find anything in the documentation that came right out and said that.

Comment: I thought I knew GNU make pretty well, but this was a feature I missed.