# How can I prevent race conditions in make?

Tags: concurrency, makefile, gnu

As the title suggests, how can I prevent race conditions in make?

My specific use case is where I want `clean` and **then** build the `all` target:

```
make -j 4 clean all
```

Should I give up and settle for `make clean && make -j 4 all`?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121620/parallel-building-with-gnumake-and-prerequisites ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way to make this work is to put this in the `Makefile`:

```
all : clean
```

which you don't want (obviously). My next idea would be:

```
clean_all: clean
    $(MAKE) all
```

That would allow you to write `make -j clean_all` but I'm not happy with it, either.

Comment: unfortunately, I think this is the only method.  It's not really acceptable for my purposes though.  Looks like I'll just stick with `make clean && make all`!

Comment: `rebuild_all: all | clean` should do what you want

Comment: @Kurt: That sounds like an answer; please create a new one and explain how this works.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot really execute in parallel a recipe that builds a target and another one that destroys it.

What a use case do you have in mind that would not be satisfied with:

```
make clean && make -j4
```

?

Comment: I think that question sounds great on a practical point of view, but `make clean && make -j4` is a full 4 characters longer than `make -j4 clean all`.  The answer to your question is that I find that solution to be perfectly acceptable, but if there is another way I can accomplish the same, I would like to know.  A different use case where that might matter be if I had to pass lengthy arguments to the make command.  In that case halving the size of the command would appeal to me.

Comment: Another reason related to what I just said is when I need to build from a different directory.  I use `make -C some/path/to/dir` pretty often.

Comment: @vmrob I see. On the other hand it is pretty fundamental that your build is one key-press process. In DEs you can specify your build command once and build it many times with one key. In the shell you can use command history to repeat any previous command. Still though, it would be nice to have in GNU make an ability to say that a certain target cannot be built in parallel with others...